# Error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./src/App` from `index.js`:

Tags: react-native

I keep getting this error when I try to run my project

My App.js code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import Router from './routes/route';
export default class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
          <Router />
        )
    }
}
```

My index.js code:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

It may be a stupid question, but i'm still learning react native

Comment: If you click f12 on App in your index.js i'ts jump to App file ?
I think all the other stuff look  good, but you need to check if the Router cause the problem-
try to replace him with View in Return render and check if its build

Comment: Are you sure the **import App from './src/App';** the path is correct?
**And if you are new to react native I would like to recommend to use functional components. Not class components. Because you can use react hooks when you are using functional components.** Thank you.

Comment: I think you should import the `App.js` like this `import App from './App';`